# Similar images displaying using canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, mouseevent

I am trying to display multiple images on canvas. The most recently added image on canvas must be draggable. This is the HTML code.

```
 <canvas id="panoramaCanvas" width=1500 height=1000></canvas>
```

I am using an object to keep the track of already added images. Each time I drag Image on canvas then this method gets called. storeData stores currently added image data.

```
var storeData = []; // Object
var panoramaImg = new Image();
var imgNumber = 0;

function handleDrop(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    e.preventDefault();
    //
    var url = e.dataTransfer.getData('text/plain');
    // for img elements, url is the img src so 
    // create an Image Object & draw to canvas
    if (url) {
        panoramaImg.onload = function () {
            panoramaCtx.globalAlpha = 0.4;
            panoramaCtx.drawImage(panoramaImg, 0, 0, this.width, this.height, 0, 0, 500, 500);
            panoramaCtx.globalAlpha = 1.0;

            storeData.push({
                imgData: panoramaImg,
                imgNo: imgNumber + 1,
                xPoint: 0,
                yPoint: 0,
            });
            imgNumber = imgNumber + 1;
        }
        //img.width, img.height, 0, 0, rangeWidth.value, rangeHeight.value
        panoramaImg.src = url;
        // for img file(s), read the file & draw to canvas
    } else {
        handleFiles(e.dataTransfer.files);
    }
}
```

On mouse event this method is called.

```
var canvasOffset1 = $("#panoramaCanvas").offset();
var offsetX1 = canvasOffset1.left;
var offsetY1 = canvasOffset1.top;
var canvasWidth = panoramaCanvas.width;
var canvasHeight = panoramaCanvas.height;
var isDragging = false;

function handleMouseDownEvent(e) {
    canMouseX = parseInt(e.clientX - offsetX1);
    canMouseY = parseInt(e.clientY - offsetY1);
    // set the drag flag
    isDragging = true;
}

function handleMouseUpEvent(e) {
    canMouseX = parseInt(e.clientX - offsetX1);
    canMouseY = parseInt(e.clientY - offsetY1);
    // clear the drag flag
    isDragging = false;
}

function handleMouseOutEvent(e) {
    canMouseX = parseInt(e.clientX - offsetX1);
    canMouseY = parseInt(e.clientY - offsetY1);
    // user has left the canvas, so clear the drag flag
    //isDragging=false;
}

function handleMouseMoveEvent(e) {
    canMouseX = parseInt(e.clientX - offsetX1);
    canMouseY = parseInt(e.clientY - offsetY1);
    // if the drag flag is set, clear the canvas and draw the image
    if (isDragging) {
        panoramaCtx.clearRect(0, 0, canvasWidth, canvasHeight);
        panoramaCtx.globalAlpha = 0.4;
        
       if (storeData.length > 1)
        {
            for (var i = 0; i <= storeData.length - 2; i++) {
                panoramaCtx.drawImage(storeData[i].imgData, storeData[i].xPoint, storeData[i].yPoint, 
                500, 500);
            }
        }

         panoramaCtx.drawImage(panoramaImg, canMouseX - 1128 / 2, canMouseY - 120 / 2, 500, 500);
        
        panoramaCtx.globalAlpha = 1.0;
        storeData[imgNumber - 1].xPoint = canMouseX - 1128 / 2;
        storeData[imgNumber - 1].yPoint = canMouseY - 120 / 2;
        console.log(storeData);
        }
     }
```

When I add first image everything works fine with mouse events but when I add second image the image data first change change to image data of second image.
[image: First image added]

[image: Second image added]

When I tried to change the position of second second image and image data of first image changes.
[image: Image data changed - main problem]

Where am I doing wrong while displaying image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are creating a single *HTMLImageElement* `panoramaImg`. The `imgData` property of all your `storeData` members are thus the same and only *HTMLImageElement* which points to the last dropped image.

Simply create a `new Image()` in your drop handler instead of reusing the same.